# Send a variable or array from javaScript to node js with ajax

Tags: arrays, ajax, node.js, express

I wanna do this:
Grab some data from my dom with javascript, save them to a variable and then send that to node js, grab that with express and finally save that into database.
client side javaScript:

```
var tags = ["apple","orange","green"];

$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/posts',
        data: { tags : tags },
        success: function(data)
        {
            alert("success!");
        }
    });
```

now I am trying to grab that data with express like this:

My server code:

```
/***** CREATE A POST *****/
app.post('/posts', function (req, res) {

  //code

  var tags = req.body.tags;

  // create that post

});
```

But that doesn't work correct. what is the problem?

Comment: can you see if you are correctly going to the `/posts` POST call, and try doing console.log(req.body.tags), and see if you are successfully receiving the data

Comment: have you used bodyParser middleware

Comment: Yes I use bodyParser. Do I need to install any esp package in order to use ajax?

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you need to do, is to use body-parser before your "post" route, otherwise it won't work. The order of the middleware matters.

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.post('/posts', function (req, res) {

  //code

  var tags = req.body.tags;

  // create that post

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You must input host and port information in the request, like this:

$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/posts',
        data: { tags : tags },
        success: function(data)
        {
            alert("success!");
        }
    });